# How to forward a Call from FreePBX to VoiceXML Application Server by dialing an Extension

Tags: text-to-speech, asterisk, pbx

I am working in a project where we need to setup an IVRS Application over FreePBX. Idea is End user will dial an extension from the SIP Phone to access the IVRS Application hosted through TTS Engine and Tomcat. So i need a call to be forwarded to the VXML server through FreePBX and continue with application over voice through SIP Phone. It can be done with Voxeo by URL Mapping once it is set to particular extension.

So looking for a Integration trick between FreePBX + Asterisk and IVRS Application to setup the particular inward call routing to the Application. In other word, how to register an IVRS Application to the FreePBX with Extension so that End User will dial the extension and gets connected with that IVRS Application and continue until hang up.Or Please let me know if i m missing the working concept of the FreePBX and Asterisk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have consult your TTS server documentation for interfaces it support.

For examples you can read app_swift.c code, designed for Cepstral TTS.

https://github.com/darrensessions/app_swift

Comment: I am using Zanzibar OpenIVR which supports Asterisk.

Comment: Asterisk itself have ivr support. Use for that v0.1 third-party-soft is very bad idea. Read asterisk book like "Asterisk the future of telephony"

Comment: Thanks for your direction. But can you give some idea how to forward an Incoming SIP call from a registered user of that PBX to an IVRS Application. Because my IVRS Application is a middleware which does webservice orchestration and that i simply can't bundle into the AsteriskNOW. So if i keep this Application Middleware generating vxml content, then how can i route an extension to access that application url through FreePBX cum AsteriskNow Server

Comment: You have read doc for your platform. Not think you can find expert for pltform with version 0.1,sorry. I am sorry, i not able teach every platform created for asterisk (becuase staff who created it just not able/willing read asterisk docs)

Comment: Ok. That's Fine. Even if we use TTS of Asterisk, can you please show me any hint to point the external URL for a particular dialed in Number.

Comment: I am sorry, i still recomend you read book. Becuase you not know terms, it is extreamly hard to guess what you mean now. If you need external put/get request use curl. If you need dialout use Dial command.